# Illustrator CC prints jagged lines

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pixelation, digital-printing

On new MacBook Pro running Mojave 10.14.4, Illustrator CC prints images pixelated and somewhat incomplete, but looks fine and smooth on screen. Checked older files from CS5 that print normal from older computer, that now with Ai CC, they print pixelated as well, ruling out printer issues.

-Anti aliased is checked, unchecked no difference
-converted to PDF, no difference
-currently updated
-reset application preferences, no change

best description of print quality would be as if it were printing what you see in pixel preview. My image is simple black and white line drawings and text, so I don't  believe its overwhelming in any way

Comment: Update- If I open the file in "Preview", the images print perfectly. While it may help narrow down the cause of the problem, I would still like to print directly from Ai. Also, if I send the Ai files to a commercial printer will they still print jagged?

Comment: Your print problem doesn't sound to be related to the quality of your file. Have you tried every single print setting? For example uncheck *Advanced > Print as Bitmap* or choose another *Transparency Flattener Preset*. It could also be in your printer's own settings (press *Setup...* in the bottom of the print dialogue).

Comment: **Note:** if user is able to open and print these from Mac OS Preview, these are being saved as `.pdf` files, not `.ai` files. I *think* this is *beyond our scope* here [ask] and probably *more properly* belongs on **[apple.se]**...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your printer is not PostSript enabled, or you haven't installed the PostScript printer driver for it. Check your printer documentation to find out if it supports PostScript.

> Non-PostScript printer drivers can conflict with Illustrator. Therefore, Adobe recommends that you set a PostScript printer driver as the default printer in macOS.

Source: [Adobe Help](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/kb/optimize-illustrator-performance-mac-os.html)

If the printer isn't PostScript enabled, a workaround is to export as PDF, or PDF compatible AI file. Open in Acrobat. Print from Acrobat.